# Background height in html

Tags: html, css, background, height

I'm trying to setup a new bg on my website, but I can't make it work. Basically I have a picture (size 50x2000 px) and I want to create repeated background. In my CSS I used :

```
#test{
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
background:url(images/bg.png); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
min-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

And it's partly working, I can see that the bg is repeated but there is a problem with hight. My web browser should squeeze the hight of the picture to fit the whole picture in a website, and right now I can see only the top of the picture, it's because the picture hight is too big 2000 px. So what I have to change in my CSS code to make the bg fit in to my website ?

Thanks

Comment: Use background-size prop as `-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;`

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. Here is what I want to achieve: oi62.tinypic.com/6dstis.jpg

Comment: There is a communication problem here — it appears that you are not describing your problem in a way that people who responded can understand clearly, so I'd recommend you to create a JSfiddle from your problem to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Ok, so here is my background jsfiddle.net/rpzguw4y/ and basically I would like to fit it to the screen, so if for example you will access my website, you will see everything, whole picture, not just a part of background, if you will access the source you will see that the picture is much larger then on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS as

```
#test
{
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
background:url(images/bg.png); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
min-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. Here is what I want to achieve: oi62.tinypic.com/6dstis.jpg

Answer (score 0):

well `background-repeat:repeat-x;` should be `background-repeat:repeat-y;` if you want to do it vertically. [look](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeaty) hear

edit, try to remove those absolut and other options so the browser can handle the rest:

```
#test{
background:url(images/bg.png); 
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. Here is what I want to achieve: oi62.tinypic.com/6dstis.jpg

Comment: leave just options: background:url(images/bg.png); 
background-repeat:repeat-xy; and let the browser do the rest. works on firefox. just to be sure check other browsers. if some have problems you can change repeat-xy to repeat-y.

Comment: I've got still the same problem. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/rpzguw4y/3/ and check how the original image looks like, it's much larger then in Result box

Comment: Well if you get my point http://jsfiddle.net/rpzguw4y/4/ you need only background and background-repeat property to make whole page background but you need to use it on body tag. the position tag brakes your background. Uncomment position tag in #test to take a look at what I mean. ofc if you use background on div property it will still work but only on the space taken by div.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
height:2000px;
```

as in:

```
#test{
width: 50px;
height: 2000px;
background:url(images/bg.png); 
background-repeat:repeat-x;
min-width: 100%;
}
```

it should solve your problem.

UPDATE:
this is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/gkxhv1h4/). the image you use in your fiddle is 900px so I set height to 900px.and I think your problem is solved.please explain more about your problem if it is not it.

Q : why do you need absolute position ? remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. Here is what I want to achieve: http://oi62.tinypic.com/6dstis.jpg

Comment: I Updated my answer . plz check :)